# Scraping data with a login using RoboBrowser

Tags: python

I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Steve/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/CBSlogin.py", line 7, in <module>
    br = robobrowser()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

And this is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import robobrowser
import http.cookiejar
import urllib.request

cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
br = robobrowser() 
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
br.open("https://www.cbssports.com/login")

br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['userid'] = 'steveb1164'
br.form['password'] = ''
br.submit()
```

Why this code is not working?

Comment: Did you even read the documentation of RoboBrowser? https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser

Comment: Changed to: from robobrowser import RoboBrowser, and that worked but now getting this error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Steve/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/CBSlogin.py", line 8, in <module>
    br.set_cookiejar(cj)
AttributeError: 'RoboBrowser' object has no attribute 'set_cookiejar'

Answer (score 0):

`robobrowser` is a module. You want to instantiate some class that's defined inside `robobrowser`, probably the class `RoboBrowser`:

```
br = robobrowser.RoboBrowser()
```

Like Yarimi mentioned, it's a good idea to double-check the RoboBrowser docs: https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser